# CALayer disappears on Custom UITableViewCell NIB after dequeue

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib, calayer, nib

I have a UITableView, where each row is a custom XIB.  One row has 4 UIButtons, that are choices, like Question, Information, etc.  When the UIButton is tapped I display an animation in a CALayer.  When the table view scrolls, the CALayer is removed, that is the animation is gone.

When the button is tapped, I crate the CALayer and the animation begins.  How can I make sure the CALayer doesn't disappear when the table is scrolled or updated?

```
class ReasonForSupportTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let animationView = AnimationView()
    var hasButtonBeenTapped = false
    var previousButtonTapped: UIButton? = nil

    //IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var questionButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var informationButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var crashButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bugButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        //set initial button
        questionButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    func createView(sender: UIButton) {

        //draw the frame
        animationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 75.0, height: 75.0)

        //change the view background color
        animationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        animationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        //add the view.
        sender.addSubview(animationView)


    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if previousButtonTapped == nil {

            //you haven't tapped a button yet

            createView(sender: sender)
            animationView.animateTo()

            previousButtonTapped = sender

        } else if previousButtonTapped == sender {

            animationView.removeAnimation()
            previousButtonTapped = nil

        } else {

            animationView.removeAnimation()

            createView(sender: sender)
            animationView.animateTo()

            previousButtonTapped = sender

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIButton to add the CALayer on initialisation, rather than when a button is tapped. You can then use the `prepareForReuse()` function to stop any animation.